# Minimise/Restore/Close buttons not showing on Modern apps, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop, modern-ui, window-manager

What is Windows 10 desktop supposed to look like?

All my Modern apps - Weather, News, Calendar, Edge etc. exhibit blank (hidden?) close, minimise and restore/maximise buttons. Ok, by design perhaps? But when I hover over them they stay blank.

The only sometimes exception is when I restore these apps after they have been minimised for a while. The minus, square and X buttons reappear for a short period, so the window buttons look like desktop apps (Chrome, iTunes, IE11 etc). But once I have closed and reopened them, they have gone blank again. I can't sense any logic to it.

Am I seeing a kind of bug?

[image: Eh?]

Comment: I get similar issues, and use Alt-Space followed by N to minimize. Especially happens with Chrome. ATI/Catalyst user here.

Comment: Interesting, so you have the inverse behaviour of this. For me Chrome and all Win32 apps always manage to show the window buttons. I have GeForce 320m (boot camp.)

Comment: It's definitely not normal, you should always see the minus, square and X symbols on those buttons. I would suspect a video driver problem.

Comment: Me too, but when I'm using the latest ATI/AMD Catalyst driver, I really don't want to play the game of going back and trying old ones and crossing my fingers.  After 20 years I may just try an Nvidia card and hope it doesn't burn out a cpu+motherboard+power supply+system drive again....

Comment: Same problem here with an AMD Radeon HD 6750M. None of their driver is working anymore with Windows 10 (I have "played the game"), this is really lame for a computer and graphic card that is barely 3 years old.  They should open source their Windows drivers if they are unable to properly maintain them themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by getting rid of the Windows Update-provided drivers for my NVIDIA 320M.

1. Uninstalling all NVIDIA graphics-related drivers in Airplane mode, both from Add/Remove Programs and Device Manager. (May need to restart a couple of times to fully remove them. Also check in Device Manager that we have gone back to "Basic video adapter" or similar.)
2. Going online again for a moment but also immediately running the **Show and hide updates package troubleshooter** from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930. **Hide the offending graphics driver.** (Very shortly after going online, Windows 10 is already looking at reinstalling the latest WHQL driver very, very soon. MS' servers just about immediately seem to tell your PC "use the cache of that driver to install the latest driver again now!")
3. Installing the original graphics driver (in my case this was on the Boot Camp 4.x usb created in OS X to work with Windows 7. I had to right click on the device in Device Manager, and choose Update Driver and point to the 64-bit NVIDIA graphics driver folder on my Boot Camp 4.x Support Software flash drive).
4. Done